# it is about application of a while loop in my code

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code:

total = []
listoforders = []

drink1 = "diet coke (number 1)"

cost1 = 150

drink2 = "coke (number 2)"

cost2 = 125

drink3 = "monster (number 3)"

cost3 = 200

drink4 = "redbull (number 4)"

cost4 = 160

drink5 = "hot black coffee (number 5)"

cost5 = 130

drink6 = "hot lemon tea (number 6)"

cost6 = 120

drink7 = "asahi (number 7)"

cost7 = 190

drink8 = "grape fanta (number 8)"

cost8 = 110

drinks = [drink1 , drink2 , drink3 , drink4 , drink5 , drink6 , drink7 , drink8]

costs = [cost1 , cost2 , cost3 , cost4 , cost5 , cost6 , cost7 , cost8]

print ("here are your drink options:")

print (drinks)

costofdrink = 0

drink = -1

while drink < 0:

```
    drink = int (input ("please type in the number of your drink 
    type 0 if you want to cancel: "))

    if drink == 0:

        quit()

    index = drink - 1

    chosendrink = drinks[index]

    costofdrink = costs[index]

    listoforders.append(chosendrink)

    total.append(costofdrink)
```

for some reason the code always stops even if the condition is not met. How do i solve this?

Comment: expected based on what drink value you input.

Comment: codeBlock have to be properly formatted. Is hard to read as-is

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is an efficient way, but I wrapped the block into a function, then called it itself.

```
def looper():
    costofdrink = 0
    drink = -1
    while drink < 0:
        drink = int(input('please type in the number of your drink: '))
        if drink == 0:
            quit()
        elif drink < 0:
            print("Choose a number greater than 0")
            drink = int(input('please type in the number of your drink: '))
        index = drink - 1
        print(index)
        chosendrink = drinks[index]
        costofdrink = costs[index]
        listoforders.append(chosendrink)
        total.append(costofdrink)
        print(listoforders, total)
        looper()
```

This worked for me.

Output:

```
here are your drink options:
['diet coke (number 1)', 'coke (number 2)', 'monster (number 3)', 'redbull (number 4)']
please type in the number of your drink: -2
Choose a number greater than 0
please type in the number of your drink: 3
2
['monster (number 3)'] [200]
please type in the number of your drink: 1
0
['monster (number 3)', 'diet coke (number 1)'] [200, 150]
please type in the number of your drink: 3
2
['monster (number 3)', 'diet coke (number 1)', 'monster (number 3)'] [200, 150, 200]
please type in the number of your drink: 0

Process finished with exit code 0
```